# Loading all Options alongside Picked in MultpleChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms

I have this form getting dynamic chosen values for the MultpleChoicesField (not ModelForm), like this:

```
 25 class SelectedVisitorsForm(forms.Form):
 26 
 27     visitors = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=True)
 28     def __init__(self,visitors_dict, *args, **kwargs):
 29         super(SelectedVisitorsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
 30         self.fields['visitors'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=visitors_dict)
```

Now, let's say I want to pass to this form options with a few of them already selected. How would I do that?

In other words, I was hoping to pass something like this in the `visitors_dict`:

```
visitors_dict = (
  (1,'First Option',1),
  (2,'Second Option',0),
  (3,'Third Option',1),
)
```

Meaning that of all options, the `First` and `Third` are already chosen. I know Django don't have anything like this, but this was just to show the general idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is simpler than that. When you instantiate the form, pass it with the argument `data` a dictionary with the keyword `visitors` as a list with the identifiers of your choices field that you want to be selected (the left most value in the choices tuples).

For example, assume you have this:

```
class SelectedVisitorsForm(forms.Form):
    CHOICE = (
        (1,'user'),
        (2, 'admin'),
        (3, 'guest'),
    )
    visitors = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=True, choices=CHOICES)
```

Then when you instantiate this form in the `views`, do it like this:

```
form = SelectedVisitorsForm(data={visitors:[1,3]})
```

And that will show the MultipleChoiceField with `user` and `guest` selected.

I hope it helps!